# How can i take random value in a dictionary from a list?

Tags: python-3.6

I want my dictionary in Python 3 takes the value randomly from a list.

```
    list = [a , b , c]

    dict =  { 1: "random value from my list???",
          2: "random value from my list???"
    }
```

How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by using [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to randomize the list:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(list)
```

Then, map the list into a dictionary, using the index of each element incremented by one as the key ([`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) is your friend here):

```
result = {v+1: k for v, k in enumerate(list)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about getting duplucate values, [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) has you covered:

```
dict = { 1: random.choice(list), 2: random.choice(list) }
```

Make sure your list isn't empty or this will raise an `IndexError`